# What is the purpose of Thread.sleep() in net-socket.io?

Tags: java, serversocket, netty-socketio

I am currently trying to learn [netty-socket.io](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) using their
[demo project](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo). I keep seeing `Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`. Can someone please tell me why this is important?

**Addition:**  To clarify, I am not asking what does the Thread.sleep() function do, obviously it pauses execution on a particular thread. I am  asking about the relevance of it in this example socket server.

```
package com.corundumstudio.socketio.demo;    
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener.*;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.*;

public class NamespaceChatLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(9092);

        final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        final SocketIONamespace chat1namespace = server.addNamespace("/chat1");
        chat1namespace.addEventListener("message", ChatObject.class, new DataListener<ChatObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, ChatObject data, AckRequest ackRequest) {
                // broadcast messages to all clients
                chat1namespace.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("message", data);
            }
        });

        final SocketIONamespace chat2namespace = server.addNamespace("/chat2");
        chat2namespace.addEventListener("message", ChatObject.class, new DataListener<ChatObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, ChatObject data, AckRequest ackRequest) {
                // broadcast messages to all clients
                chat2namespace.getBroadcastOperations().sendEvent("message", data);
            }
        });

        server.start();

        //Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        server.stop();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` suppose to causes the currently executing thread to sleep for the specified number of milliseconds. I don't knew natty-socket but i guess it will do the same there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that this does not have anything to do with the server at all. This `Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` has simply paused execution of the program. To make this answer intuitive, I will change `Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` to `Thread.sleep(4000)` in the posted code block.

ie,  this would start the server, run it for 4 seconds and then stop the server.

This seems to only be here to fulfill its purpose; which is to start and stop the server, as this was taken from a demo project.